# linear algebra and matrices, dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $W = \{p(B) : p\ \text{is a polynomial with real coefficients}\}$, where
>   $B = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. The dimension $d$ of the vector space $W$ satisfies
>
> 1. $4 \le d \le 6$
> 2. $6 \le d \le 9$
> 3. $3 \le d \le 8$
> 4. $3 \le d \le 4$

I solved the question up to the thing give below. I have considered $B$ as $x$ and I tried to find an $n$ such that the set $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots,x^n,\ldots\}$ contains only finitely many elements, but I could not achieve that. Tell me whether my approach is correct or not. If not, what is the other method to follow...

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct but you haven't implemented it! I think we have to interpret $1=B^0=I$.

Note that because $B^3=I$ we have

$$\begin{align}p(B)&=a_0+a_1B+a_2B^2+a_3B^3+\cdots a_nB^n
\\ &=a_0I+a_1B+a_2B^2+a_3I+a_4B+a_5B^2+a_6I
\\ &=\left(\sum_{k\geq 0}a_{3k}\right)I+\left(\sum_{k\geq 0}a_{3k+1}\right)B+\left(\sum_{k\geq 0}a_{3k+2}\right)B^2\end{align},$$
so that ${I,B,B^2}$ is certainly a spanning set for $W$.

I don't believe that it is difficult to show that ${I,B,B^2}$ is linearly independent so that $d=3$.